# Replace the ServerName in a UNC Path

Tags: c#, unc, replace

I want to write a method to swap out the server name in a UNC path.  So if I have `"\\server1\folder\child"` I want to swap in `"\\server2\folder\child"`.  Various attempts to do this have run into jagged edges with .net's handling of backslashes (regex, Path.Combine).  I will not know the name of "server1" at runtime.

Here's a snippet I have been testing in LinqPad, while it works it seems pretty hacky:

```
string path = @"\\server1\folder\child";

var uri = new Uri(path);

string newPath = @"\\server2\";

foreach (var part in uri.Segments)
{
 if (part == "/")
     continue;

 newPath += part;
}

var x = new Uri(newPath);

uri.Dump();

x.LocalPath.Dump();
```

Comment: What various attempts? Show some...

Comment: and "\server1\folder\child" is not UNC path... (unlike "\\server\share\path\file.txt")

Comment: @Bash.d sorry, I inadvertently posted the question before I was done entering it.

Comment: Based from your question, you can try to use "String.Replace" to transform "server1" to "server2" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx to change

Comment: @AwesomeProgrammer no good, see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right path (no pun intended)

Quick edit of your code leaves this:

```
string path = @"\\server1\folder\child";

var uri = new Uri(path);

string newPath = @"\\server2" + uri.AbsolutePath.Replace('/', '\\');

var x = new Uri(newPath);
```

Comment: Well, I think I'm going to do that.  Though it seems my initial attempts to use Split to dump the parts into an array didn't work because I was getting the blanks that resulted (I'm not clear why they aren't a problem in some of the Split examples in other answers, and it's Friday and I don't care any more).  Your way is neater than mine, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `string.Format` method;

```
string path = @"\\server1\folder\child";
string server = "server2";
string newPath = string.Format(@"\{0}\{1}" + server + @"\{3}\{4}", 
                               path.Split('\\'));
```

Or this using `Substring` and `IndexOf` methods;

```
string s = @"\\server1\folder\child";
string server = @"\\server2";
string s2 = server + s.Substring( s.Substring(2).IndexOf(@"\")+2);
```

Comment: A problem I ran into with Split() was that at runtime the string really looks like "\\\\server1\\folder\\child", and when I tried to dump the results into an array I got the blanks that resulted (and I don't want to get into it, but another dev here preferred I avoid split altogether).  Is String.Format doing something magical there to avoid them?  Because your snippet definitely does what I want in LINQPad.

Comment: String.Format is not doing anything with the Split operation. It is just taking the given element number from the string array and assigning them as per the formatted string. You are seen double `Backslashes` for a single `Backslash` because one `Backslash` is used as an escape character. I am using `@` to escape them here in this example.

Comment: I know why I see double backslashes, but I realize now I was misinterpreted something in your answer earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you tried with `Regex`es, but I think this should basically do what you're looking for:

```
var path = @"\\server1\folder\child";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(path, @"\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]*\\", @"\\server2\");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string ReplaceServer(string path, string newServer)
    {
        return path.Replace(path.Split('\\')[2], newServer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And to prove that there's a thousand different ways to skin the cat:

```
string oldPath = "\\testserver1\\folder\\child";    
string newServer ="testserver2";
var subPath = oldPath.Split(new []{'\\'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(Int32.MaxValue)
    .ToList();
subPath.Insert(0,newServer);
var newPath = Path.Combine(subPath.ToArray());
newPath = @"\\"+newPath;
newPath.Dump();
```